# How to get the default size back for a div by toggle in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs in my application that seperates the screen with the content and sidemenu.

```
<div class="splitter-left ">
    <div class="close-left-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="toggle-menu">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid content-close">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <p>Home</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <p>About</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <p>Contact</p>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>


<div class="splitter-right">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <strong>Header options</strong>      
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my styling for **splitter-left** and **splitter-right**

```
   .splitter-left {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25%;
            max-width: 300px;
            min-width: 250px;
            background-color: #fff;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: -35px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

  .splitter-right {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 85%;
                margin-top: 10px;
                position: relative;
                left: 50px;
                min-height: 400px;
            }
```

I also made a JQuery function to activate the button to hide and show the **splitter-left**

This is my function in JQuery

```
 $("#toggle-menu").click(function () {
   if ($(".content-close").toggle()) {
   $(".splitter-left").toggleClass('sidemenu-close')
   $(".splitter-right").css({ width: '100%' });
    else {
   $(".splitter-right").css({ width: '75%' });
         }
   });
```

And this is the styling for the method **toggleClass** for **sidemenu-close**

```
.sidemenu-close {
            width: 0% !important;
            min-width: 0% !important;
        }
```

When I click on the button **Click me** the `splitter-right` class gets a width of 100% (this is working). When I click on the button again the `splitter-right` doesn't go back to the default size of 75%.

How can I get the default size back when I click on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it with the following solution:

```
$("#toggle-menu").click(function() {
    $(".content-close").toggle();
    if ($(".splitter-left").hasClass('sidemenu-close')) {
        $(".splitter-left").removeClass('sidemenu-close')
        $(".splitter-left").css({
            width: '25%'
        });
        $(".splitter-right").css({
            width: '85%'
        });
    } else {
        $(".splitter-left").addClass('sidemenu-close');
        $(".splitter-right").css({
            width: '100%'
        });
    }
});
```